# nginx proxy to Apache/PHP is slow

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

My setup:

- nginx is listening on port 80 and working as a reverse proxy (plus directly sending static files)
- Apache 2 is listening on port 8080
- PHP is running in Apache 2
- All running on one server (no internal network latency)

My problem:

Static files now are very fast, but everything going through the proxy takes a lot of extra time.

One example is a "search-as-you-type" tag suggestion box. When I connect to Apache directly though port 8080 everything is fine and the server responds quickly (~50 ms). When I use the "normal path" through port 80 (nginx -> Apache) every request takes about 15 times as long (~750 ms).

I expected *some* more time. Right now requests are not leaving the server in any way, so why do they take so much more time to process? How do I make them faster?

Is there any way I can use persistent connections between nginx and Apache?

Is there any way to benchmark where exactly that additional 0.7 second is added?

Main interest: Can I find out if this time comes from internal processing in nginx (e.g. hostname table lookup) or is it the connection to Apache. Is nginx waiting for an open socket - or what happens here?

Comment: Why are you using Apache at all?

Comment: Because I didn't have time to check/fix all schripts on the server for compatibility with another webserver. I may be able to do that in the long run - but right now it was "hdd crash - so I had to set up a new server and desided to try something new, because Apache was eating so many resources on static files".

Comment: How do you proxy requests to Apache? If you use localhost:8080, try to use 127.0.0.1:8080 instead.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 seems to be a little faster than localhost - but it's still slow.

Comment: Is there anything in error.log?

Comment: Nothing of interest. Only regular "favicon.ico not found" and similar stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I finally found my problem - and it looks as if I was causing my own problems:

I misconfigured **[limit_req_zone](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html)** throttling my server down to a crawl slower than expected.